# SharePoint REST: Column does not exist error

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I'm calling a REST API with a SharePoint Designer workflow on SharePoint online. I'm setting the column name with a variable, and when i put the variable into my URL to call it it says "Column [name] does not exist".

Annoying part is when I call just /items? I can see the column in the result, but if I try select it or filter by it I get 'does not exist'. I have alot of these columns similarly named, and I get the error for all of them.

I am using the internal name, I have tried adding "OData_" to the front. I've tried typing the url manually in the browser and entering values (incase the variable was causing issues) but I get the same error, column does not exist. but i can see it them I call all items. :(

so I have quite a few columns with naming convention "[Q#] Score [#]" eg "Q4 Score 2". The internal name that's clearly appearing in the full items results is "Q4_x0020_Score_x0020_2".

This works:
https://MYSITE.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/intranet/CorpServices/QSR/_api/web/lists/GetbyTitle('Audit')/Items?

and I get big full normal REST results that includes the line:
0

However if I try:
https://MYSITE.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/intranet/CorpServices/QSR/_api/web/lists/GetbyTitle('Audit')/Items?$Select=Q4_x0020_Score_x0020_2

Then I get:
-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPExceptionColumn 'Q4_x0020_Score_x0020_2' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

I expect to be able to select that column (and the dozens like it) but none work. I've searched all similar problems on the forum and they've usually got a spelling mistake or forgot the ODATA_ but i cant seem to get the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to be working intermittently.... So it was in fact just a naming error...... Half of the columns were [Q#]_x0020_Score_x0020_[#] and half were [Q#]_x0020_score_x0020_[#]. The word "Score" was capitalized on some and not others. I Didn't realize the HTTP Calls were case sensitive. Now I have added a bunch of if statements to handle the different variations haha. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the naming convention you are on an older version of SharePoint.  The *x0020* is the value for a space.  Ideally when you first create the column you would name it without the spacing. For example UserInformation.  Then come in and edit the name after the fact and call it User Information.  If you click on the title name and look at the URL, you will see what the actual name of the column is at the end of the URL.  It is case sensitive because you can have a column named score and Score which is ultimately why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Must load all fields like this

```
 var lists = context.Web.Lists;
            context.Load(lists);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = @"";

            var list = lists.GetById("file.guid");
            var listitems = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(listitems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            var creationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            var newItem=list.AddItem(creationInformation);

            var fields = list.Fields;
            context.Load(fields);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```